# Use Summon in springboot application to fetch secrets via a command in docker and inject it as environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, cyber-ark

I have a spring boot application and I have stored the secrets in Vault (a secrets management platform). and im using Summon for fetching secrets. the application is dockerized, and in the docker file I specified a Summon command to fetch the secrets and inject them as environment variable inside of the application.yml properties.

```
CMD summon -f secrets.yml -e ${APP_RUN_PROFILE} java -jar ssc-main.jar \
    --spring.profiles.active=$APP_RUN_PROFILE \
    $EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

- in my secrets.yml file I have the path to the secrets.
- in the application.yml I used

```
cfg.app.token.smth.username="#{environment.SMTH_USERNAME_SECRET}"
```

My questions are:

- Is this environment variable injected after the application has started?
- Since, the the properties are loaded during the application startup, does it still load the application with empty values and then inject those variables after the application has started?
- Is it a correct way of injecting those secrets?

Comment: If you're using a command-line wrapper, I'd expect the environment variable to be injected _before_ the application starts; ignoring Spring, the process would see it as an ordinary environment variable.  I wonder if [Spring Cloud Vault](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-vault/) might be a simpler and more direct integration here.

Comment: thanks for your response, we cannot use cloud vault, since we should store the secrets in the PAM vault which is different from the cloud vault.